# Failed to clone remote repository

Tags: version-control, vbe, rubberduck

I can not clone and get a 403 error code. The user name and password I entered are the ones I use to login to GitHub and are correct. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: FWIW Source Control is to be marked as experimental next release or so I heard

Comment: are you saying I can't clone, push etc as in other IDEs?

Comment: That's the intent. However remote functionality appears to be borked, hence we're marking SC feature as "experimental", and it's undergoing a major overhaul in the v2.1 cycle.

Comment: I have Build 2.0.11.2453 (MSIL)